# How to control visibility of canvas image via button outside the canvas(ChartJs)?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, chart.js

I placed an image with a line inside a chart like below
[image]

To do this I used `draw` function of `Chart.helpers.extend` like below

```
  let originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
    const base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/classic-icons/512/087.png";
Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
    draw: function () {
      originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);
      let chart = this.chart;
      let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        let xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
        let yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.top+40);
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
        ctx.lineTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.bottom);
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
        ctx.drawImage(base_image, xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index) - 15, 50, 30, 30);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }
  });
```

Up until this point it was a bit challenging but big challenge is controlling the visibility of inserted all images and drawn black lines via button(like legend filter buttons of chartJs).

I thought that I might use `clearRect()` to clear what I drew but problem is having more images and lines due to dynamic data.

How can I solve this?

JSFiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/xazpjqb2/1/

**EDİT**
I came up with an answer about wrapping chart render function with a global varibal to get control of it.Then Chart.update() does the trick.

Here my solution : https://jsfiddle.net/1nwbv5k9/

Answer (score 1):

You could enhance Chart's base class by a new property which determines if an image should be shown or not. e.g.

```
Chart.showImage=true;
```

This property could be used inside your extended draw function and ultimately call or not call `ctx.drawImage`.

```
  if (Chart.showImage) {
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index) - 15, 50, 30, 30);
  }
```

With this in place you can simply set `showImage` to false and update your chart like this:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
createImg(1);
function clearChart(index) {
  //functions will go here to clear placed elements 
  Chart.showImage = false;
  myChart.update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I appreciate it.I came up with also a solution.Check my post again